# How do I use an API in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, fetch

I was looking for a cool way I could automate some interesting news articles on my discord server. I wanted to use webhooks at first but then decided to go with APIs. I looked all around and saw that I should go with New York Times API but when I went to code it, it came up with a few errors.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = require("./token.js");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const prefix = '!';

const trim = (str, max) => str.length > max ? `${str.slice(0, max - 3)}...` : str;

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');

});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'news') {
        const { file } = await fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key=').then(response => response.json());

        message.channel.sendMessage(file);

    }
    }).then((state) => {
        assert(state.action === 'DONE', 'should change state');
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            assert.isNotOk(error, 'Promise error');
        });
throw
client.login(token);
```

This is my code, I know this is probably riddled with mistakes but I am just starting out with node.js
I looked at the example from the discord.js website and took some stuff from there. I don't know what I should do and if you could explain it out a little to help me learn that would be great. I keep getting the `Unhandled Rejection Promise Warning` and the `Cannot send an empty message` errors. I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: First of all, it doesn't look like you're providing an API key in the part of the URL that needs an API key. I don't think NYT will give you access to their articles without one, probably.

Comment: I have one but I just didn't want to share it

Comment: Oh yeah, that's totally fair; I just wanted to make sure you knew where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the async/await to get the `results` array from the API response, then send the details in embeds. You can either send the first article, a random article or more than one articles.

The following should work, it sends the first three articles:

```js
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const token = require("./token.js");

const client = new Client();
const API_KEY = 'QerEdX953-NOT-REAL-hdvgx7UPs';
const prefix = '!';

client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'news') {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key=${API_KEY}`,
      );
      const data = await response.json();

      if (data.results.length === 0) {
        return message.channel.send('There are no top stories for you today ');
      }

      const embed = new MessageEmbed();
      // you could also get the number of stories from args[0]
      const MAX_STORIES = 3;

      data.results.slice(0, MAX_STORIES).forEach((result) => {
        embed.setTitle(result.title);
        embed.setDescription(result.abstract);
        embed.setURL(result.url);
        embed.setTimestamp(result.published_date);

        if (result.multimedia.length && result.multimedia[2]) {
          embed.setThumbnail(result.multimedia[2].url);
        }

        message.channel.send(embed);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      message.channel.send('Oops, there was an error fetching the API');
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I keep getting this "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"

Comment: You must have missed the `async` keyword. Have you copy-pasted my code? Because the message handler is an async function.

Comment: now it says that client is not identified

Comment: Ah, yes, that was my fault, I missed that. I've just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Comment: You're welcome. I've just made another update to include the timestamp and change the thumbnail used.

Comment: Now as a extra little question. Do you know a better news api for tech news?

Answer (score 0):

The response from the [Top Stories API](https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/top-stories-product/1/routes/%7Bsection%7D.json/get) does not have a `file` key and so is `undefined`. You want to destructure `results` to access the articles array.

The error message says that you cannot call `sendMessage` with an empty message (`undefined` in this case).

I'm not sure of the message you want to send but you can send the link to the first article with the following code, for example.

```js
const res = await fetch(`https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key=${NYTIMES_API_KEY}`)
const { results } = await res.json()

if (results.length) {
  message.channel.sendMessage(results[0].url)
} else {
  message.channel.sendMessage('No articles found')
}
```

Comment: Ok so now it says this  "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and still this "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict`"

Comment: Interesting. Can you share the output of `console.log(await fetch('https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/technology.json?api-key=NYTIMES_API_KEY').then(response => response.json()))`? You have to replacee `NYTIMES_API_KEY` with your key, of course.